# Spring Integration JDBC inbound-channel-adaptor Conditional Update

Tags: spring, jdbc, ejb, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration JDBC to poll a table and then send the record to external system, which is accessed via remote EJB call. I created the jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter like this:

```
<int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter channel="ch1" data-source="ds" row-mapper="rm" query="..." update="...">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="60000">
        <int:transactional />
    </int:poller>
</int-jdbc:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="ch1"/>

<int:splitter input-channel="ch1" output-channel="ch2"/>

<int:outbound-channel-adapter ref="messageDispatcher" method="dispatch" channel="ch2"/>

<bean id="messageDispatcher" class="a.b.c.MessageDispatcher"/>
```

`MessageDispatcher`'s `dispatch` method will do the remote EJB invocation. The problem is, I can't make the jdbc update to be conditionally executed. For example if the EJB returns false, then I don't want to update the record's flag status. How to make this integration flow? What should I add/change in the configuration file?

Comment: Try to throw a RuntimeException instead of "return false".

Comment: Then the whole transaction will be rolledback, isn't? I want to only update the data that has been successfully processed by the remote EJB.

Comment: ??? Isn't that what do you want? When TX is ralled back, the update won't be performed. If that remote EJB is successful, you perform update.

Comment: No, what I want is that just update the successful process, and ignore the failed process. At first, I think the update attribute is mandatory. But in the end I knew that it is optional and I can move the update process in the outbound channel adapterfor each record. I already have implemented my own outbound channel adapter to do this. Thanks.